# Use CSS to resize inline images

Tags: css, web

I write technical docs. Sometimes I need to include an inline image of a GUI icon in my instructions. The inline image is often a screenshot of the icon. Sometimes, the screenshot is much larger than the surrounding text, like in the image below. It looks bad, and that makes me sad.

[image: example of inline image that is larger than surrounding text]

Is there a combo of CSS rules to ensure that the inline image is the same size as its surrounding text?

Comment: Why not use font awesome?

Comment: @TonyHensler what makes you think FontAwesome has icons that are the same as the application Kayce is writing Technical docs for? In technical docs you want the image to be a close as possible to the actual interface.

Comment: It may look bad, but your users now not only know the look, but also size of the icon they are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the CSS Unit "em" where 1 em represents 1 times the current font size. Means you can set the `max-width`/`max-height` of the img-Tag to 1em. Use `vertical-align: middle` to horizontally center the image.

```css
h1 img,
h3 img {
  max-width: 1em;
  max-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    Big header (<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/male-user-silhouette_318-35708.jpg">)
</h1>
<h3>
    Small header (<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/male-user-silhouette_318-35708.jpg">)
</h3>
```

Here's a JSFiddle you can mess around with: [https://jsfiddle.net/qvd56t62/6](https://jsfiddle.net/qvd56t62/6/)

Comment: Bingo. Although, I don't think it makes sense to also constrain `max-width` to `1em`. I sometimes work with icons that are wider than they are long. In those cases the icon's height would be smaller than the surrounding text.